# Is PHP static field real static?

Tags: php

I feel that the PHP static field is static merely throughout a request.

I have this code in my controller class:

```
static $a = 2;

public function debug()
{
    var_dump(self::$a++);
    var_dump(self::$a++);
}
```

No matter how many times I request `debug`, it outputs:

```
int 2
int 3
```

Very different from my knowledge on `static` in java.

Comment: Static does not mean constant. It means it belongs to the class rather than the instantiated objects of that class. As for "merely static throughout the request": Each request is a new instance / thread of PHP, if you want to preserve variables across requests you have to use the session (`$_SESSION`) or some kind of other storage (database, files, ...).

Comment: Static properties in PHP exactly same as in Java.

Comment: @Amruthls. I think these are different questions. And what ccKep mentioned ' Each requests is a new instance / thread of PHP', might be the answer to my quesion.

Comment: @bijiDang. That's right as per WEB server, every new request is going to be a new thread for server side languages like PHP... and that's why the output is like you have mentioned... You can share the values of variable either by using session or by saving it into the database and retrieve it back for new request.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, static in PHP is "real" static.

What you observe is result of different application life cycle in PHP and Java.

In Java, web application run inside WebServer(HTTP server), which after initial class load, on following requests reuse what it already loaded. For this reason class(and static properties) initialization occurs only once in application life cycle.

In case of typical PHP web application it looks a bit different.

HTTP server is independent application which listens for HTTP requests and runs PHP on demand(not all HTTP requests must be passed to PHP).
PHP is run as a separate process, request is passed and after answer is received process is discarded. Every request is handled by completely separate process. Classes(and static properties) are loaded and initialized from scratch every single time.

Below is simple(very) HTTP server written in PHP which will simulate how Java WebServer works.

```
<?php

class Server {
    private $socket;
    private $routes = [];

    public function __construct($address, $port, $backlog = 5) {
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        if ($socket === false) {
            throw new Exception("socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
        }
        if (socket_bind($socket, $address, $port) === false) {
            throw new Exception("socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
        }
        if (socket_listen($socket, $backlog) === false) {
            throw new Exception("socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
        }
        $this->socket = $socket;
    }

    public function listen() {
        while( ($requestSocket = socket_accept($this->socket)) !== false ) {
            $this->handleRequestSocket($requestSocket);
        }
        throw new Exception("socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($this->socket)));
    }

    public function registerController($url, $controller) {
        $this->routes[$url] = $controller;
    }

    private function handleRequestSocket($socket) {
        $buffer = "";
        while(false !== ($part = socket_read($socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ))){
            $buffer .= $part;
            if(substr($buffer, -4) == "\r\n\r\n") break;
        }
        $buffer = trim($buffer);
        echo "\n======\n$buffer\n======\n";
        $response = $this->handleRequest($buffer);
        if (null === $response){
            socket_write($socket, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
        } else {
            socket_write($socket, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: ".strlen($response)."\r\n\r\n$response");
        }
        socket_close($socket);
    }

    private function handleRequest($raw) {
        $lines = explode("\r\n", $raw);
        $req = explode(" ", $lines[0]);
        $method = $req[0];
        $url = $req[1];

        if(isset($this->routes[$url])) {
            return (string) (is_callable($this->routes[$url]) ? $this->routes[$url]($raw) : $this->routes[$url]);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class ControllerWithStatic {
    private static $static = 0;
    public function handle() {
        return "Hello from static: " . (self::$static++) . "\n";
    }
}

$server = new Server($argv[1], $argv[2]);

$c = new ControllerWithStatic();
$server->registerController("/", "Hello world\n");
$server->registerController("/closure", function(){return "Hello world from closure\n";});
$server->registerController("/static", [$c, 'handle']);
$server->registerController("/static2", function(){
    return (new ControllerWithStatic())->handle();
});

$server->listen();
```

Run it using

```
php server.php HOST PORT
```

e.g.

```
php server.php 127.0.0.1 8080
```

Now open in your browser `http://127.0.0.1:8080/static` or `http://127.0.0.1:8080/static2` and you will get

```
Hello from static: 0
Hello from static: 1
Hello from static: 2
...
```

Number will be increasing as long as you don't restart server.